# Is $7$ the only prime followed by a cube?

Tags: prime-numbers

I discovered [this site](http://www.numbergossip.com/7) which claims that "$7$ is the only prime followed by a cube".  I find this statement rather surprising.  Is this true?  Where might I find a proof that shows this?

In my searching, I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/211379/125959), which is similar but the answers seem focused on squares next to cubes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Factor $x^3-1$.

Comment: More generally, for each $k$, there is at most one prime that is followed by a $k$-th power: that number is $2^k-1$, but it is not always a prime: you need $k$ prime but not all primes $k$ give a prime $2^k-1$. See [Mersenne prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).

Comment: Of course the above comments are related to the fact that the polynomial $x^k-1$ has $x=1$ as a root, and so $x-1$ divides that polynomial.

Comment: @barto I definitely did not expect this question to be received so positively.  I also did not expect it to be a simple answer, but I'm not as deep into mathematics as the users here.  One thing to always remember on SE sites is that your average users (at least the ones asking questions) are probably not an experts.  While you may have great questions/answers exploring the mysteries of mathematics, the likelihood I understand it is low so I am unlikely to vote on those.  Also, simple questions can lead to clever, simple answers.

Comment: @barto It will take much more then that to offend me.  I was attempting to shed light on this phenomenon of simple questions getting lots of upvotes.

Comment: A spin off is a proof that no even powers grater than 2 follow a prime number. [For $n>2$ is no primes followed by even powers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679648/for-n2-is-no-primes-followed-by-even-powers?noredirect=1#comment1427068_679648)

Answer (score 296, accepted):

This is certainly true. Suppose $n^3 - 1$ is prime, for some $n$. We get that $n^3-1 = (n-1)(n^2 + n + 1)$ and so we have that $n-1$ divides $n^3 - 1$. If $n-1>1$ then we're done, as we have a contradiction to $n^3 - 1$ being prime.

Comment: Wow, amazing!! Did you just make the proof yourself now, or has it been known to you already (or a similar type of proof)?

Comment: @Tomas: this is a fairly standard sort of argument, the kind you would learn how to write down in any good course in elementary number theory. Many textbooks cover this and related topics.

Comment: "We have that" this should be of interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447697/mathematical-writing-why-should-we-not-use-the-phrase-we-have-that

Comment: it puzzles me how this deserves a great answer badge comparing to answers like this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218131/enumerations-of-the-rationals-with-summable-gaps-q-i-q-i-12 which needed some serious thinking. I am not saying the answer is not a good one, but it is almost utterly trivial.

Comment: @Lost1: just there are more people able to undestand this one

Comment: @SergeyGrinev yes, but that does not make it a good question.

Comment: @Lost1 Congratulations, you've just observed that voting system of SE is screwed globally. (Still, it seems to quite well achieve to find local maxima).

Comment: While that's a nifty equation it didn't really highlight to me why that when n-1>1 means we are done.

Comment: I'm with @BeowulfNode42 on this.  This answer doesn't really explain anything unless you already understood it, and I don't.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 I agree, the next answer highlighted it a little better. The concept is that the definition of a prime is that their only factors are $1$ and themselves, if $n -1 = 1$ then the number still meets the requirement of being prime (and if $n -1 <1$ it can only be zero). Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Lost1, I think, but I am neither a sociologist nor a psychologist, it mostly depends on the question. This question is pretty good, in the sense it asks something curious (in fact I had it linked on SOF and I came here to check it) and pertinent to the site, while the one you are pointing to is really specific and not really interesting for non-math people. Don't get me wrong, the answer you cite is amazing, but it is an answer niche

Comment: Many years after the original question apparently, I believe that the whole thing written+comments it is more of social investigation than a mathematical one. Is funny to check how members of this site understand how it works. Judging out of the above mentioned comments, you can understand how mathematical adequacy can be far away from the social one...(p.s. this all has nothing to do with the guy who answered the question, but mostly for the comments they received)

Answer (score 264):

$$
x^3 - 1 = \underbrace{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}.
$$
Being a product of two numbers, the expression over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ is composite UNLESS $(x-1)=1$.  That happens only if $x=2$, so $x^3=8$.

Comment: While both sides of the equation are always equal, x^3-1 cannot be a prime if it is equal to the multiplication of 2 numbers unless 1 of them is a 1. So x-1=1 when x is 2. While (x^2 + x + 1) = 1 when x = 0 or -1 they do not produce a positive integer when put into (x^3-1) and so cannot be prime either.

Comment: This answer is easier to understand than the accepted one by @pgadey. I mean, what does "If n−1 > 1 We're done" mean? Shouldn't it be more like "n must equal 2 for n-1 to be 1, hence not a prime"?

Answer (score 62):

**Key Idea** $\ $ *Composite* polynomials [take *composite* values](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/670070/242)) (except for *finitely* many values)

Indeeed, suppose that $\ f(x)\color{#c00}{\ne 0}\ $ is a composite polynomial: $\, f(x) = g(x)h(x)\,$ with $\ g,\,h\color{#c00}{\ne \pm1}.\,$ Then $\, f(n) = g(n)h(n)\, $ is a composite integer if $\,g(n),\,h(n)\,\neq\,  0,\,\pm1.\,$ The possible exceptions to this are $ $ *finite* $ $ in number: $ $ when $\,n\,$ is a root of $\ g,\, h,\, g\pm1,\,$ or $\, h\pm1, \, $ all of which are $\color{#c00}{nonzero}$ *polynomials*, hence have *finite* sets of roots. $\ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ For a specific composite polynomial $\,f = gh\,$ this yields a simple algorithm to enumerate its finitely many prime values: test if $\,f(n)\,$ is prime as $\,n\,$ ranges over the roots  of $\,g\pm1\,$ or $\,h\pm1.\,$  Applying this to $\, f = x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2\!+x+1)\,$ quickly yields the sought result.

Hence the method used in the other answers is a special case of a method that works generally. Furthermore, this is an instance of a *general philosophy* relating the factorizations of polynomials to the factorizations of their values (see [said answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/670070/242)) for much more on this viewpoint).

Comment: I did not downvote, but, imo, someone with 108k reputation should not post an answer to a clearly overrated question 2 hours after 3 answer have not emerged, and your proof is an overkill. Given that the OP has asked the question, it is pretty clear your answer is unlikely to be accessible for his level of mathematics.

Comment: @Lost1 Answers teach many readers besides the OP. My sole motivation here is to teach math (not to play the SE rep game). This is a perfect teaching opportunity - a simple problem whose key ideas lead to many interested related results, including deep open problems (follow the links). This is one of the tantalizing aspects of number theory - that simple looking problems often encode deep, interesting math. Things like this are what sparked me to study number theory. I strive to pass along the mathematical torch, hoping that it will similarly spark others, for there lies much beauty.

Comment: I agree with you, Bill Dubuque. Having read other answers of you I've noticed that you quite often want to show an underlying, more global concept. I appreciate this style of answering (some do not apparently, which I can understand), but perhaps this time you are a little exagerating.

Comment: @barto I'm not exaggerating. The study of this and related matters leads quickly to interesting and challenging unsolved problems in number theory, such as nonlinear analogs of [Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) on primes in progressions (e.g. [Bunyakovsky's conjecture).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) Any methods that solve these or related problems would probably lead to major breakthroughs. See Chapter 6 of Ribenboim's *The New Book of Prime Number Records* for a very readable discussion on this.

Comment: @BillDubuque I suppose you're right, I think you're talking about subjects I can't yet imagine nor understand, so I bet I can not yet realize the importance of what's in your answer.

Answer (score 40):

You want to know when $x^3-1$ is prime. This expression can be written as $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, So it is always divisible by $(x-1)$. If a prime is divided by $(x-1)$, so $x-1=1$ or $x=2$ and $x^3-1=7$.

Answer (score 17):

Wouldn't $-2$ also be a prime followed by $-1$ which is a cube of $-1$.
As $x^2 + x +1$ will also equal one for $x=-2$.

Comment: Negative integers can not be prime.

Comment: @Zafer: It is very common to take the point of view that $-p$ is prime whenever $p$ is.

Comment: You could make the same argument for x=0 but [to my understanding](http://www.numbergossip.com/1) primes are positive integers larger than 1.

Comment: While in ring theory the additive inverses of primes are also considered to be prime, the context of the question and the linked site are most likely only referring to positive natural numbers.

Comment: This interpretation depends on your definition of "followed by." I take it to mean "moving away from zero," not "increasing toward positive infinity."

Comment: @Jeremy's answer neglects the detail that $$\begin{align}\text{if}\ x&=-2,\\x-1&=-3 \neq 1\\ \therefore (x-1)^3 &\neq (x^2+x+1)\end{align}$$ It's $x-1=1$, not $x^2+x+1=1$. But let's take a look at $x=-1$ for a second. True, $$\begin{align}((-1)-1)^3&=((-1)-1)((-1)^2+(-1)+1)\\
&=(-2)(1+(-1)+1)\\
&=-2\end{align}$$ which is a "negative prime" although it actually composite, because it can be divided by $-1$. But that's not all. $-1$ is followed not by $-2$, but $0$, which by definition is not prime.

Comment: @Greg Then $-7$ would be a secondary solution. But I wonder about your interpretation of "followed by". $0$ is followed by $1$ and/or $-1$?

Comment: Jeremy, It's $x = -1$, not $x = -2$.

Comment: actually when x=-2 the equation (x^2+x+1) = ( (-2)^2 + (-2) + 1 ) = (4-2+1)=3, and the equation ( (-2) - 1 ) = -3.  So (x^3 - 1) = (-3) * (3) = -9 which is not a prime for being composed of the multiplication of 2 integers, neither of which are 1.  So even if you disregard the requirement that it be a positive integer it is still not prime when x=-2

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink: I manually converted your answer to a comment. One only needs 50 rep points to comment everywhere. You are almost half-way there! To earn the remaining reputation the most efficient way is to post good questions and good answers, good luck.

Comment: I'm not a number theory crack, but in all contexts of Mathematics that I've encountered up to now, it is a convention that primes *in $\mathbb{Z}$* are taken to be positive.